# group list elements based on another list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two lists: `inp` and `base`.

I want to add each item in `inp` to a list in `out` based on the position in `base`.

The following code works fine:

```
from pprint import pprint as print

num = 3
out = [[] for i in range(num)]
inp = [[1,1],[2,1],[3,2],[7,11],[9,99],[0,-1]]
base = [0,1,0,2,0,1]

for i, num in enumerate(base):
    out[num].append(inp[i])
print(out,width=40)

[[[1, 1], [3, 2], [9, 99]],
 [[2, 1], [0, -1]],
 [[7, 11]]]
```

I would like to do this using the `NumPy` module (`np.array` and `np.append` or etc.).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `base`and `inp` as NumPy arrays, we could do something like this -

```
# Get sorted indices for base
sidx = base.argsort()

# Get where the sorted version of base changes groups
split_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(base[sidx])>0)+1
# OR np.unique(base[sidx],return_index=True)[1][1:]

# Finally sort inp based on the sorted indices and split based on split_idx
out = np.split(inp[sidx], split_idx)
```

---

To make it work for lists, we need few tweaks, mainly the indexing part, for which we can use `np.take` to replace the indexing into arrays as listed in the earlier approach. So, the modified version would be -

```
sidx = np.argsort(base)
split_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.take(base,sidx))>0)+1
out = np.split(np.take(inp,sidx,axis=0), split_idx)
```